# Exponential distribution related questions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Suppose that the inter-arrival times of male customers entering the bank are iid exponential random variables with $\frac{1}{\lambda_1}$ and for those females are iid exponential random variables with $\frac{1}{\lambda_2}$. Find the distribution and expected value of $Z_f$, the number of female customers arriving at the bank between two successive male customers.

The question bothers me for a while. Please help me out!!!

Answer (score 1):

Conditional the male first arrival time $T$, derive the number of female jumps in $[0, T]$. This the conditional distribution of $Z_f$ on $T$.  From here, you can get the marginal of $Z_f$.

Answer (score 1):

If $Y$ is the arrival time between successive male customers $Y\sim \text{Exponential}(\lambda_2)$

and interarrival times that are exponential with rate $\lambda_1$ are indicative of a Poisson process with rate $\lambda_1$, therefore the number of female customers arriving given $Y$ is $Z_f|Y\sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda_1Y)$.

I haven't been able to find the distribution as it doesn't seem to marginalize out well, but the expected value is as follows:

$$\begin{split}E(Z_f)&=E(E(Z_f|Y))\\
&=E(\lambda_1Y)\\
&=\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}\end{split}$$

Comment: @Jellufish I do not understand the last part. We are going to estimate $E(Z_f)$, right?

Comment: @E.J. Yes, that was a typo. I had $X$'s before and I forgot to switch that one to $Z_f$.